# problem with img in html

Tags: html, image

i write this code in a html page but it doesn't show the image what is problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>register page</title>
<body>
</head>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/me/images/register.jpg" width="600" height="395">
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have provided a full file path, not a relative path or URL.

If your website lives in `htdocs`, try changing the path to `/me/images/register.jpg`

Answer (score 5):

If you're running it served from the actual server, the image `src` is invalid. It needs to be relative to your application root. In other words, if you application root is `C:/xampp/htdocs/me`, then your image tag should actually be `<img src="/images/register.jpg" width="600" height="395">`

Answer (score 0):

did you check if is it the image available on that folder?

it would be nice if you are using relative path:

Relative Path URLs

Relative paths change depending upon what page the links are located on. There are several rules to creating a link using the relative path:

links in the same directory as the page have no path information listed filename sub-directories are listed without any preceding slashes weekly/filename links up one directory are listed as ../filename

How to determine the relative path:

1. Determine the location of the page you are editing. This article is located in C:/xampp/htdocs/me/ folder on your site.
2. Determine the location of the page or image you want to link to. The Beginner's Resource Center is located here: C:/xampp/htdocs/me/images/
3. Compare the locations and to decide how to point to it From this article, I would
   need to step up one directory (to/library) and then go back down to the beginning directory
4. Write the link using the rules listed above:

   <img src="images/register.jpg" />